# Top K Numbers from Un Ordered Array Without using Sort or Linq OrderBy methods

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, sorting

I was just binging/googling about inbuilt functions in .Net to get Top K numbers/elements from **un-sorted** array **without using linq order by or sort methods**.

Another way I can write my own TopK method by implementing selection algorithm.

But my main intension is **"Is there any inbuilt function which uses selection algorithm like quick select or heap."**

If there is no inbuilt TopK method **I would like to know how to do with Linq or .Net without using Sort and OrderBy methods.**

Reason for avoiding Sort and OrderBy is "they follow sorting algorithms internally not selection algorithm". Please correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: Do not assume anything - measure.

Comment: Don't you want to use http://powercollections.codeplex.com/? Something like OrderedBag or OrderedSet. Its behavior seems to be like priority queue (or binary heap).

Comment: Pretty confident .NET has no (public) heap implementation.  You'll have to write your own.

Comment: Do you want N-th element in sorted array or array of top K elements ?

Comment: @Valentin, I heard about that PowerCollection but never used. Probably I will have look at it. Thank you.

Comment: @brz, Top K elements. I have also highlighted the main points too.

Comment: Can the down voter please give some comments? Anything wrong with the question? Isn't worth of knowing O(n) solution (using selection algorithm) than O(n log n) solution (using Sorting). Just want to let you know that 'simply down voting will not helps me in improving/correcting myself.

Comment: I have entered a feature request on [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), Issue #[103](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/issues/detail?id=103)

Comment: In the meanwhile, a foreach that compares each item in the list and only keeps the top K elements of a list of n elements should be somewhere close to O(n).

Comment: Thank you Brennan, that would helps. In fact I also requested in MSDN, but unfortunately lost the link.

Comment: An implementation of a similar approach can be found on [Li Chen's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen): [An efficient Top K algorithm with implementation in C# for LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/an-efficient-top-k-algorithm-with-implementation-in-c-for-linq)

Comment: That's really a nice trick Brennan.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
void Main()
{
    var kth = 4;
    var arr = new int [] {5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1};
    var val = getItem(arr, kth);

}   

int getItem(int[] items, int kth)
{
    if (kth == 0 || kth > items.Length)
    {
        throw new  IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    else if (items.Length == 1 && kth == 1)
    {
        // only 1 item so return it
        return items[0];
    }
    else if (items.Length == 2)
    {
        if (kth ==1)
        {
            // two items, 1st required so return smallest   
            return (items[0] <= items[1] ? items[0] : items[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            // two items, 2nd required so return smallest   
            return (items[0] <= items[1] ? items[1] : items[0]);
        }
    }
    var middleItem = (int)((items.Length)/2);
    var pivot = items[middleItem];

    var leftarr = items.Where(s => s < pivot).ToArray();
    if (leftarr.Length + 1 == kth)
    {
        //our pivot is the item we want
        return pivot;
    }
    else if (leftarr.Length >= kth)
    {
        // our item is in this array
        return getItem(leftarr, kth);
    }
    else
    {
        // need to look in the right array
        var rightarr = items.Where(s => s >= pivot).ToArray();
        return getItem(rightarr, kth - leftarr.Length);
    }
}
```